# Is there any method to change the icon image to an local image in prime react?

Tags: css, jsx, primereact

I'm trying to change a button icon image to an image on my computer, yet prime react doesn't seem to allow me to do this. I have tried:

1. linking the button to an external style-sheet and changing background image from there.
2. Using an inline style attribute ***style={ }***

No avail, any help is appreciated!

Comment: No idea but if you correct your tagging you might atttact people with prime react knowledge instead of PrimeFaces

Comment: Ok just updated the tags

Answer (score 0):

it's possible if you call the icon path in a state of your  HOC (component class) and update the state inside an event `(onClick)` by calling `setState()`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './beside-App-js.css'
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        icone: "pathToCurrent/img.png"
    }

    onChangeFunction = (newimg) => {
        this.setState({
            icone: newimg
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {icone} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>

                <button onClick={this.onChangeFunction.bind(this,"newpath")}>change <img src={icone} /></button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/abdeldouichi/pen/QXgmQp)

Comment: No doubt this works, but only on click. My problem is that primereact won't let me change the icon of a button permanently (the icon you first see on the button when the page loads up).

Comment: it's not the `onclick` who change the image it's the methode `this.setState`, you use it in events (`onClick`, `onChange` ...) or at loading of component (`componentDidMount() ` {)  it's will change data or icone directrly